# Where to put default-servlet-handler in Spring MVC configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In my `web.xml`, the default servlet mapping, i.e. `/`, is mapped to Spring dispatcher. In my Spring dispatcher configuration, I have `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` and `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` which allows me to map url to controllers either by its class name or its `@Requestmapping` annotation. However, there are some static resources under the web root which I also want spring dispatcher to serve using default servlet. According to [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler), this can be done using `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` tag.

In the configuration below, there are 4 candidate locations that I marked which are possible to insert this tag. Inserting the tag in different location causes the dispatcher to behave differently as following :

**Case 1** : If I insert it at location 1, the dispatcher will no longer be able to handle mapping by the @RequestMapping and controller class name but it will be serving the static content normally.

**Cas 2, 3** : It will be able to handle mapping by the @RequestMapping and controller class name as well as serving the static content if other mapping cannot be done successfully.

<del>**Case 4** : It will not be able to serve the static contents.</del> *Removal Note : This was a bug when implementing a controller which has a method mapped to `/**` but does not have explicit request mapping on the controller class name.*

Therefore, **Case 2** and **3** are desirable .According to Spring documentation, this tag configures a handler which precedence order is given to lowest so why the position matters? and Which is the best position to put this tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="webapp.controller"/>
    <!-- Location 1 -->

    <!-- Enable annotation-based controllers using @Controller annotations -->
    <bean id="annotationUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <!-- Location 2 -->
    <bean id="controllerClassNameHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <!-- Location 3 -->
    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <!-- Location 4 -->
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <!-- All views are JSPs loaded from /WEB-INF/jsp -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Spring sets the value of the order of `HandlerMapping` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which gives the lowest precedence order. When the dispatcher configuration is loaded for the first time, `DispatcherServlet` will use this values to sort the list of `HandlerMapping`'s.

If the explicit value of order is not set, then all handler mapping object will have the same order of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Thus, after the sorting, the order of the handler mappings will remain the same as the order of the beans definitions. [this sounds like a bug in the implementation of dispatcher]

Therefore, if the order values of handler mappings are explicitly set, it is safe to put `<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>` tag anywhere in the bean definition.

Here is example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="webapp.controller"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <!-- Enable annotation-based controllers using @Controller annotations -->
    <bean id="annotationUrlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="controllerClassNameHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <!-- All views are JSPs loaded from /WEB-INF/jsp -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is down to poor wording in the documentation.

> It configures a `DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` with a URL mapping (given a lowest precedence order) of `"/**"`

I think this means you *should* give it a lower precedence order, and not that Spring will do this automatically.

I don't understand why putting it at location 4 doesn't work, though, I see no difference between location 4 and location 3 - the handler adapter should not interfere with the mapping precedence.

Comment: But you cannot set the order of this mapping through this tag.

Comment: @gigadot: The order is implicit in the order of the bean definitions.

Comment: You are right about that there are no different between location 3 and 4. I have updated the question and answer. Spring does give the lowest precedence order to handler mapping which is configured by `mvc:default-servlet-handler` tag but it also gives the same value to other handler mapping if the explicit value is not set. BTW, thank you for your response.