# Spring Controller to handle all requests not matched by other Controllers

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller, mapping

I have a series of Controllers with Request Mappings that match certain URL's. I also want a Controller that will match any other URL not matched by the other Controllers.
Is there a way to do this in Spring MVC? For example, could i have a controller with @RequestMapping(value="**") and change the order in which Spring Controllers are processed so this Controller is processed last to catch all unmatched requests? Or is there another way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to handle all 404s? But possibly do something useful, rather than return 'not found'?

Comment: Yes your idea would work. Have you tried it? See https://github.com/stormpath/spring-mvc-rest-exhandler/blob/master/example/src/main/java/com/stormpath/blog/spring/mvc/rest/exhandler/DefaultController.java for example

Comment: Yes, i want a way to process URL's not matched by any other Controller i have made.

Comment: Wouldn't the default controller you have provided in that link be matched before other requestMappings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/how-to-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0/51167549#51167549

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your base url is like that= http://localhost/myapp/ where myapp is your context then myapp/a.html, myapp/b.html myapp/c.html will get mapped to the first 3 method in the following controller. But anything else will reach the last method which matches **. Please note that , if you put ** mapped method at the top of your controller then all request will reach this method.

Then this controller servrs your requirement:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ImportController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "a.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getA(HttpServletRequest req) {
        ModelAndView mv;
        mv = new ModelAndView("a");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "b.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getB(HttpServletRequest req) {
        ModelAndView mv;
        mv = new ModelAndView("b");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "c.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getC(HttpServletRequest req) {
        ModelAndView mv;
        mv = new ModelAndView("c");
        return mv;
    }

@RequestMapping(value="**",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getAnythingelse(){
return "redirect:/404.html";
}
```

Comment: After this configuration my swagger stopped working. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2532

Comment: use @RequestMapping("/anything/")  instead of @RequestMapping("/") for this configuraration

Comment: But that will handle only non mapped requests under `/anything`

Comment: then remove the last method from this class value="**", and use custom exception handler... which will make sure that any non mapped request goes to a certain 404 page

Comment: Exception handler wont solve my problem, want to handle it inside @RequestMapping method. Anyhow Thanks & plus1.

Answer (score 15):

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/**", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public ResponseEntity<String> defaultPath() {
    LOGGER.info("Unmapped request handling!");
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unmapped request", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This will do the work with proper order of controller matching. It will be used when nothing is matched.

Comment: This is problematic. For some reason, this controller method catches request to static resources too.

Answer (score -1):

You should use "*" as the value but inside the brackets

```
@RequestMapping(value={"*"}, method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String allRequests() {
    return "index.html";
}
```