# How to match only paths in /[^/]+ with Spring @RequestMapping?

Tags: regex, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need the following:

Any request to

- https://localhost:8443
- https://localhost:8443/
- https://localhost:8443/test
- https://localhost:8443/api

and so on, should be forwarded to

https://localhost:8443/a/web/index.html

Now, this is how I managed to do that:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/a/web/index.html";
    }
}
```

#### The problem is:

This also matches https://localhost:8443/api/ (note the / at the end).

This is a problem because that's where I want the Spring Data REST base path to be:

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/
```

> `/api != /api/` when it comes to REST endpoints.

#### What should work but somehow doesn't

I have tried several different regular expressions but I am still not able to accomplish what I want. For example ([demo](https://regexr.com/4baad)):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/[^/]+", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Will now work for Spring Data - I'm getting all the resource information I expect, but accessing https://localhost:8443/ is now broken and the web-client cannot be reached anymore.

The same goes for

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^/]+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

which behave like `/*` (also matches the next `/`).

This issue is already haunting me for weeks and still no solution insight.

---

This whole question can also be seen as:

Why is `"/[^/]+"` not matching https://localhost:8443/whatever ?

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594644/spring-controller-to-handle-all-requests-not-matched-by-other-controllers

Comment: @NestorSokil Hm, I don't think this answer can help me here. Just adding an endpoint which matches everything unmatched does not help here - it is actually the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043618/how-do-i-map-spring-mvc-controller-to-a-uri-with-and-without-trailing-slash/45258671#45258671

Answer (score 0):

Regex are usually not the fastest thing to try.
You can send a list of paths to

```
 @RequestMApping(value={"", "/", "/test", "/api"},  method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

See [Multiple Spring @RequestMapping annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513031/multiple-spring-requestmapping-annotations)

Comment: Sorry, this is not a generic solution which is what I am looking for.